# How to install svn repository in my shared hosting server

Tags: svn, hosting

I plan to host a site in a shared hosting environment, where multiple developers can work on the site simultaneously even after hosting, so I'm thinking about creating the subversion repository on the same server space.

Is it advisable to do this, and if so, how can I install the svn repository in my server space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that kind of a setup should be fine. You will need some kind of shell access to the shared server to svn update your files.If you already have the files on your server, you can create a repository by doing svn import to a brand new repository. If the repository already exists, clean out your folder on the server and do a svn checkout.

Make sure to have your svn server on a different machine for redundancy.

Answer (score 6):

I am bit late but my answer can help someone.

First, login with ssh or putty into server and try below steps

**1. Create a Repository**

```
svnadmin create /svnrepos
```

**2. Create a SVN User**

```
vi /svnrepos/conf/svnserve.conf
```

In that file add these three lines:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

Create a password file:

```
vi /svnrepos/conf/passwd
```

In that file add a line for your user:

add users in the format : user = password

```
tony = mypassword
```

**3. Import Your Project**

(assuming you’ve put your project files in /projects/myrailsproject)

```
svn import /projects/myrailsproject file:///svnrepos/myrailsproject
```

**4. Start the SVN Server as Daemon**

```
svnserve -d
```

Done! You should now have a svn server running with one project named myrailsproject.

Try checking it out of the repository:

```
svn co svn://192.168.0.2/svnrepos/myyrailsproject
```

Since we set anon-access to none you should be prompted for username and password which you created in the file /svnrepos/conf/passwd.

***These steps were taken from [here](http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/)***